# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str - pandas

Tags: pandas, position

I'm working on a personal project, and  I need to delete some rows from my dataframe, and the easiest way I found is to move a column to the position 0, then remove the rows whose 'headline' contain certain values.

```
import pandas as pd 
HC=pd.read_excel('Headcount 2020.xlsx')
cols=list(HC.columns)
HC=HC[cols[7]+[cols[0:7]]+cols[8:44]]
```

By doing this I got the error

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

However, in the example I was following this morning, with the same code, it worked perfectly

```
    import pandas as pd 
    df=pd.read_csv('pokemon_data.csv')
    df['Total'] = df.iloc[:,4:10].sum(axis=1)
    cols=list(df.columns)
    df=df[cols[0:4]+[cols[-1]]+cols[4:12]]
```

I ignore what it can be. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `HC=HC[[cols[7]]+[cols[0:7]]+cols[8:44]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
HC=HC[[cols[7]]+cols[0:7]+cols[8:44]]
```

---

the problem is that `cols[7]` is a str

```
#HC=HC[cols[7]+[cols[0:7]]+cols[8:44]]
```

Comment: yes, It solved my issue. Thank you so much. I feel so dumb now